# javascript remoting not working

Tags: javascript-remoting

I have a VF page with very few input HTML tags and I want to pass these values to the controller via javascript remoting on a click of Submit.
I see that my submit function is being called but for some reason the method on the controller is not called. I went over and over but the code seems to be fine. This is what I wrote, do you see any issue?

**My Controller method:**

```
global with sharing class ReservationController {    
  @RemoteAction
  global static boolean Submit(string FName, string LName, string Email, string Phone,                   
                               string Company, string Website){
       system.debug('in submit');
  }
}
```

**My javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#form1').submit(function(){
            var ok = true;

           ...some code...

            if(ok){
                //submit
                console.log("form ok");                 

                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                    '{!$RemoteAction.ReservationController.Submit}',
                     $('#firstName').val(), $('#lastName').val(), $('#theEmail').val(),  
                     $('#thePhone').val(), $('#theCompany').val(), $('#theWebsite').val(),
                     function handleResult(result, event) { alert(result); },
                     {escape: true}
                );                  
            }
            else{
                console.log("form not ok");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Try renaming your `submit` method name to something else. I've had issues in the past using common names for the methods.

Comment: Default escape is true, you do not need to include that as a paramater.

Comment: Everything looks perfect, instead of passing parameters directly, try to assign to variables and use them in call like var fname = $('#firstName').val();

Comment: I've followed all of your suggestions but still the controller method is not being invoked. Any advice how to debug this?

Comment: one way is use alerts at all single lines and see till where your execution stops .Also try to see if there are no plugin dependency issues thats occuring.Hope this helps

Comment: with an alert I am able to see the submit is called and executed, till its last part of the JS remoting which is not, but I don't know why. There is no error in the console as well...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the apex page has your controller set as the page controller?